# Error 403 on laravel application on php version 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-403

On deploying my laravel application, I encounter this error:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0"

while using any PHP version below 8.1. On adjusting the PHP version to version 8.1 I get error 403. Kindly assist.

Comment: Is your project on the server assigned the correct group and user, and are the access permissions correct?

Comment: Where are you deploying? Maybe restart server or check permissions.

Comment: In cPanel, I am getting the same problem.